# ¿Mostrar ruta imagen seleccionada galería Lollipop? Android

Tags: android, cámara

Hola cuando quiero obtener la ruta de la imagen seleccionada con la versión de Android Lollipop me devuelve null. ¿Como puedo hacer para que me vaya en todas las versiones de Android?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
intent.setType("image/*");
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Source"), SELECT_PHOTO);

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Cursor cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(data.getData(), null, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
    result = cursor.getString(idx);
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: estas sacando la foto con la camara u obtienes de la galeria?

Comment: De la galería. Haciendo lo mismo con Jelly Beans me va bien. La imagen me la muestra en todos pero a la hora de obtener la uri absoluta de la imagen con Lollipop me devuelve null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Desde una [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29144367/file-path-return-null-always-in-lollipop-android) en Stack over flow en ingles, (en google buscas tu error y hay una infinidad de preguntas-respuestas)

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String wholeID = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(selectedImage);
    String id = wholeID.split(":")[1];

    String[] column = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    String sel = MediaStore.Images.Media._ID + "=?";

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().
    query(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        column, sel, new String[] { id }, null);

    String filePath = "";

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(column[0]);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: Ya lo se, lo he estado mirando y no me van, por eso pregunto por aquí a ver si alguien me puede ayudar.

Comment: probaste este codigo @EricRetamero

Comment: Funcionó muchas gracias.